# I wanted to open a file with the module of python "open", and trying to make it in fragments, then, it appears this phrase "list index out of range"

Tags: python

```
data2 = open("D:/python-ml-course-master/datasets/Netflix_movies/metadata.csv","r",encoding = "utf-8")

cols = data2.readline().strip().split(",")
n_cols = len(cols)

counter = 0

main_dict = {}
for col in cols:
    main_dict[col] = []

for line in cols:
    if counter > 0:
        values = line.strip().split(",")
        for i in range(len(cols)):
            main_dict[cols[i]].append(values[i])
    counter = counter + 1

print("El data set tiene %d filas y %d columnas"%(counter, n_cols))
```

Comment: In the traceback you can see the error is on `main_dict[cols[i]].append(values[i])`, so most likely `i > len(values)`

Answer (score 0):

Your last data line ends on a `\n`. When splitting the (empty) content of the line after that, you do not get enough `values` for the columns.

Fix:

```
for line in cols:
    if counter > 0:
        values = line.strip().split(",")
        if len(values) == len(cols): 
            for (name,v) in zip(cols,values): 
                main_dict[name].append(v) 
                counter = counter + 1
        else:
            print(f"Not enough data in '{values}' to write a line")


print("El data set tiene %d filas y %d columnas"%(counter, n_cols))
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, i fixed as you explain me, it runs but it appears another problem, the variable "values" doesn´t receive the values of all the data. the variable values only gets one value in all the iteration. the problem is with the csv or with the code? and is it a way to fix it? and again, thank you for the answer

Comment: @kevin- edit your question and add the first 10 lines of your data formatted as code (so it respects line ends)

Comment: I´m sorry, I´m new with stackoverflow, can you tell me how can i write the 10 lines of my data as a code in a comment? I understand you that I write the 10 lines of the data that is in the csv in a comment, am I right? Because when i write the ten lines, it tells me that the characters passed

Comment: @kevin you edit your **question** (not a comment) - there is a small [edit] button below it. you format it as code by identing each line by 4 spaces.